# (design) 2 Elements blocking each other

Tags: c#, textbox, label

simple question here:

I have a problem with one of my labels.

[image]

My problem is that the (!!!) label corresponding to the textbox "Datei Name" is being blocked by said textbox. Is there a setting that I have missed that puts said label behind/in front of the textbox?

How the (this part of the) program works:
When something is incorrectly entered in one of the textboxes a label containing (!!!) and a Messagebox show up which tell the user where the error is located.

Comment: I'd use [ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) instead of `Label`. See: [How to: Display Error Icons for Form Validation with the Windows Forms ErrorProvider Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/display-error-icons-for-form-validation-with-wf-errorprovider?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: @MaciejLos I kind of already have that principle working via Messageboxes. It's just there to help the user find the problem instead of intimidating them with a serious error message. I have already seen some people straight up giving up after getting 1 error instead of trying to find the cause of the problem, which is why it resulted in this approach.

Comment: ErrorProvider is using when you want to display error message and indentify control which causes that error. In other words: why to force doors wide open and create custom "Error handling platform" when there is ready to use solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentioned in the comment to the question, i'd use [ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) instead of spending time to write code to manipulate controls on the form.

Here is MSDN example: [How to: Display Error Icons for Form Validation with the Windows Forms ErrorProvider Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/display-error-icons-for-form-validation-with-wf-errorprovider?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

How it works?

When the form is NOT valid, you'll see:

[image]

When you move cursor over icon, you'll see error details:

[image]

If you've got [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/Download.aspx), you can use this script to check how it works:

```
void Main()
{
    MyForm mf = new MyForm();
    mf.Show();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class MyForm: Form
{
    private TextBox TxtDateiName = null;
    private TextBox TxtDateiNr = null;
    private Label Label1 = null;
    private Label Label2 = null;
    private Button BtnValidate = null;
    Dictionary<Control, ErrorProvider> ValidatedControls = null;
    
    public MyForm()
    {
        Initialize();
    }
    
    private void Initialize()
    {
        this.Size = new Size(250, 180);
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.Text = "ErrorProvider Example";
        Label1 = new Label(){Text="Datei Name:", Location =new Point(10,12), AutoSize = true};
        Label2 = new Label(){Text="Datei Nr:", Location =new Point(10,42), AutoSize = true};
        TxtDateiName = new TextBox(){Name="TxtDateiName", Size= new Size(140,24), Location =new Point(78,10)};
        TxtDateiNr = new TextBox(){Name="TxtDateiNr", Size= new Size(140,24), Location =new Point(78,42)};
        BtnValidate = new Button(){Size = new Size(220, 48), Text = "Validate", Location = new Point(10, 78) };
        BtnValidate.Click += BtnValidate_Click;
        this.Controls.Add(Label1);
        this.Controls.Add(Label2);
        this.Controls.Add(TxtDateiName);
        this.Controls.Add(TxtDateiNr);
        this.Controls.Add(BtnValidate);
        
        ValidatedControls = new Dictionary<Control, ErrorProvider>();
        ValidatedControls.Add(TxtDateiName, new ErrorProvider(this));
        ValidatedControls.Add(TxtDateiNr, new ErrorProvider(this));
        ValidatedControls[TxtDateiName].SetIconAlignment(TxtDateiName, ErrorIconAlignment.MiddleRight);
        ValidatedControls[TxtDateiName].SetIconPadding (TxtDateiName, 2);
        ValidatedControls[TxtDateiName].BlinkRate = 1000;
        ValidatedControls[TxtDateiName].BlinkStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ErrorBlinkStyle.AlwaysBlink;
        ValidatedControls[TxtDateiNr].SetIconAlignment(TxtDateiName, ErrorIconAlignment.MiddleRight);
        ValidatedControls[TxtDateiNr].SetIconPadding (TxtDateiName, 2);
        ValidatedControls[TxtDateiNr].BlinkRate = 1000;
        ValidatedControls[TxtDateiNr].BlinkStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ErrorBlinkStyle.AlwaysBlink;
        
    }

    private void BtnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool ans = true;
        foreach(var k in ValidatedControls.Keys)
        {
            switch(k.Name)
            {
                case "TxtDateiName":
                    ans = IsValidName(((TextBox)k).Text);
                    ValidatedControls[k].SetError(k, ans ? "" : "Name is wrong!");
                    break;
            
                case "TxtDateiNr":
                    ans = IsValidNumber(((TextBox)k).Text);
                    ValidatedControls[k].SetError(k, ans ? "" : "Number is wrong!");
                    break;
            }
        }
        
        ans = ValidatedControls.All(kvp=>kvp.Value.GetError(kvp.Key)=="");
        MessageBox.Show(ans ? "Form is valid!" : "Form contains errors!", "Information");
        if(ans) this.Close();
    }
    
    private bool IsValidName(string dName)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(dName, @"^(\w{3,})$");
    }
    
    private bool IsValidNumber(string dNumber)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(dNumber, @"^(\d{3,5})$");
    }
    

}
```

Do not forget to add references (F4) to: `System.Windows.Forms.dll`
and then add the following namespaces:

```
System.Drawing
System.Windows.Forms
```

**Final note:**

This is just an example. So, the code is not optimized.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll use it in the future. The problem somehow solved itself after a restart.